# Fixed decimal places double and power of ten format in java

Tags: java, numbers, format, double

I'm writing some code in Java that is supposed to manipulate data from a text file.
In the text file are coordinates saved. The layout of the numbers is always: `5.000000000000000+0`
The data is read, manipulated and then printed back into the file. The printing part is not yet working, as the number of decimal places varies and I haven't succeeded to append the power of ten in the shown way.
For the decimal numbers I tried:

```
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(15);
```

and

```
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(15);
```

but it still displays more digits sometimes. 
How can I achieve the shown format for my double numbers or at least get the right amount of decimal digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use String.format:

```
    double x = 1.1231523235;
    System.out.print(String.format("%.5f", x));
```

that would print

```
    1,12346
```

and if you want dot as the delimiter use

```
    System.out.print(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"%.5f", x));
```

Comment: Depending on your locale, it might be `1.12346`

Comment: @Bathsheba, there is a function String.format that takes a locale argument as well, so the delimiter can be changed.

Comment: Absolutely! put that in the answer to attract very many upvotes.

Comment: @Bathsheba ... and now we wait :)

Comment: That helped to get the right amount of decimal digits, thank you! Any idea how I get the number to be always #.##################-1 with the last two digits being the exponent of *10; for example 4.000*10^2 = 4.000+2?

Comment: @dAhkS I don't understand what you need exactly, give me more examples.

Comment: The output of the numbers is now like this: 
`#.#####`
with the right amount of decimal digits. That's fine so far.
But the data has to be formatted like this:
`#.#####+x`
where x is the exponent of the power of ten. For example:
Instead of `40.00000 = 4.00000E+1` I want `4.00000+1` to be printed.
My problem is to append the exponent without the E directly to the number.

Comment: If zero before the exponent are not the issue, you can use `.replace("e","");` like so: `System.out.println(String.format("%.5e", x).replace("e", ""));` @dAhkS

Comment: Almost perfect, now I'm getting for example `5.00434+01` 
How can I set the power of ten to always be only one digit? Like:  `5.00434+1` ?

Comment: try something like this:
`while(string.contains("+0")){ string = string.replace("+0","+");}` @dAhkS

Comment: Thank you! Now the output is exactly as I wanted it to be!

Answer (score 1):

here an example

```
    NumberFormat form = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    form.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);
    form.setMinimumFractionDigits(4);
    form.setMaximumFractionDigits(6);

    double number = 23.993838939239;
    System.out.println("format : " + form.format(number));
```

i'm not sure about what you are asking for, but if you want to completely format a double number you have to specify the Minimum Integer Digits, the Minimum Fraction Digits and the Maximum Fractions Digit.
You should post the piece of code that gives you the problem for more accurate help. The result of this piece of code is :

```
 23,993839
```